# Links to other terms within a term definition in Sandcastle

Tags: .net, documentation, sandcastle, shfb, maml

I'm composing a glossary using MAML. For example:

```
    <glossaryEntry>
      <terms>
        <term termId="BasicCommercialPack">BasicCommercialPack</term>
      </terms>

      <definition>
        <para>
          It's a set of <link xlink:href="#ProductFeaturePack">feature packs</link>
        </para>
      </definition>
    </glossaryEntry>
```

This would work, but I'd like to know if I can refer to terms as I would do using `<relatedEntry termId="[some term id]" />` element as part of a **definiton** instead of using a regular `<link>` element.